# git rebase and SHAs mentioned in log messages

Tags: git, logging, rebase, sha

Sometimes the log message for a git commit will mention the SHA of other commits.  This happens in the suggested log message for `git revert` and you also may add it by hand ('fixed bug introduced in abcd0123').

When rebasing, the SHAs of commits change.  Is there a way I can automatically fix up the log messages to have the new SHAs?  In general, this might not be possible in 100% of cases (a commit might disappear altogether, be squashed, etc).  But 90% of the time a simple rebase leaves a one-to-one correspondence between the original and the rebased commits, so it should be possible to remap the SHAs in log messages.

I have tried `git rebase --verbose`, which I hoped would print something like

```
Applying: My log message here.
  old commit was 01234
  new commit is abcde
```

I could then use that to manually fiddle the log messages (with a further rebase... which would in turn change the SHAs... so it would be awkward, but nonetheless possible).  But as far as I can tell `--verbose` doesn't print more information than the normal mode.

Is there some magic tool which will rebase and rewrite the log messages for me?  In the absence of ponies, can I convince `git rebase` to print more information about old and new SHAs so I can do the job myself?

Comment: One thing to be aware of: after a rebase, typically the original commits are no longer reachable and are eligible for garbage collection. This is the primary reason that `git rebase` doesn't do what you want automatically, unlike `git revert` or `git cherry-pick`. Unless you have another branch or tag pointing to the original commits, these commits will eventually be removed from the repo. But if you have another branch or tag pointing to the original commits, the rebase causes some serious issues, most importantly that the same changes will appear in more than one place in the repo.

Comment: Not to worry, the original branch is still there and pushed upstream.  My rebased branch (which I give a different name) is likely to be an attempt to 'clean up' the history before merging it into the master branch, or as an aid to bisecting.  Both the original and the rebased branches will be deleted soon after the merge to master.

Comment: The was [a discussion](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg261244.html) on one kernel developers' mailing list about exactly this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sometimes the log message for a git commit will mention the SHA of other commits[...]When rebasing, the SHAs of commits change. Is there a way I can automatically fix up the log messages to have the new SHAs?

You can use `git patch-id` to find commits that apply the same changes, the most brute-force method would be

```
git rev-list --no-merges --reflog --all \
| git diff-tree --stdin -p \
| git patch-id | sort > patch-ids

awk '{print $2,$1}' patch-ids | uniq -Df1
```

to find every set of commits in your repo that apply similar patches.  A bit of `git log --grep=` applied to the results, and perhaps some restraint on your rev-list args, should get you where you want to go.

On GNU/anything replacing the uniq with

```
uniq -f1 --all-repeated=separate | awk '{print $1}' | awk '{$1=$1; print}' RS=
```

groups the commit ids for you.  You could use `join` or some more awking to achieve the same effect elsewhere.

You can add [git notes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes) to a commit (or to any object), that might help if you're trying to distribute warnings about what happened.

Comment: Do the arguments to `git rev-list` have to be reordered?  On my repository, `git rev-list --all -g --no-merges` prints 19111 lines, but `git rev-list --no-merges -g --all` prints only 69.

Comment: Well, today I learned there's a distinction between `--reflog` and `--walk-reflogs` aka `-g`.  Use `--reflog` instead of `-g`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks to be working.  Now I could write a thingummy that checks all the log messages on a branch, makes sure any SHAs mentioned in a commit are ancestors of that commit, and if not prompts you to change them.  Though I think having `git rebase` print more info would be better.

Comment: `git rev-list --reflog --not --all` looks like a useful set, it's everything that's in the reflogs but not currently reachable, so that'll catch all abandoned-by-rebase commits, but your test won't catch cherrypicks, I think you want reachable commits whose log message refers to unreachable ones.

Comment: ... erm, for "won't catch" read "won't work on", I need to pack it in for the night...

Comment: Well, I'm not concerned with checking all commits in a repository, just making sure the log messages in a particular branch are sane -- probably just the master branch, in fact, before I push it upstream.

Comment: I'm thinking of writing a Python script for this purpose using `gitpython`. Is the thingummy available somewhere online?

Comment: No, I haven't written the thingummy, I was just speculating that one day I could.